# understanding preg_match_all use and regex '/./u' pattern

Tags: php, regex

I found this function to remove diactrics from a string in UTF-8 and I don't know why does it have to use the preg_match_all function and what exactly does it's pattern do?

```
function strtr_utf8($str)
{
   $keys = array();
   $values = array();
   preg_match_all('/./u', 'ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃęóąśłżźćń', $keys);
   preg_match_all('/./u', 'EOASLZZCNeoaslzzcn', $values);
   $mapping = array_combine($keys[0], $values[0]);
   return strtr($str, $mapping);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just exploding the string into one-character array.
You get 2 arrays of characters, and then combine them into a `key=>value` pairs array.
Which in turn is used for `strtr` character replacement -> strange UTF8 characters are replaced with ASCII ones.

Why we explode it with `preg_match_all()`? Why using regular expressions at all?

I guess, because of the `/u` key, which makes it work with UTF8 characters. If using normal PHP string functions like `str_split()`, it would explode them in `bytes` not `characters`, and it will be a mess, because of multi-byte structure of UTF8. Like, the letter `Å` takes 2 bytes in UTF8 string.

Basically, what you get is:

```
$mapping = ['Ę' => 'E',  'Ó' => 'Q', 'Ą' => 'A', ... 'ń' => 'n'];
```

You could also use multi-byte strings library functions, like this:

```
str_replace(mb_str_split($from), mb_str_split($to), $str);
```

Comment: I was wondering why not just explode the string, but I didn't know it might not work with UTF-8. And why is there a slash at the front? is it sort of quotation for `u` key?

Comment: Slash in the front and back is just the format of regular expressions. As in, for example, `"/regular expression/keys"`. See PHP regular expressions reference: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains everything :)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, an other possible way to do the same thing:

```
$input = 'ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃęóąśłżźćń';

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $input);

print_r($result);
```